# Skip index in element buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

So I remember there was an opengl function that you could call to set an index value you could  have in your element buffer that would cause opengl to skip over the triangle.

Like if your skip value was -1 you could have 3 triangle, but have one be removed.

Element Buffer Object: 1 2 3 -1 -1 -1 3 2 4

I hope I'm getting my point across. I am having trouble finding the function online.

Comment: [`glDrawRangeElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawRangeElements.xhtml) or do you mean [Primitive Restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot merely skip a vertex in the index list. There is [primitive restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive_Restart) functionality, which allows a specific index to mean "start a new primitive". But that's different from skipping a vertex.

If you're drawing a `GL_TRIANGLES` primitive, and you want to change the index list such that certain triangles don't appear, simply repeat the same index 3 times. That will generate a triangle with no area, and since you used the same index, the VS will only need to be invoked once. If you used the same index as the last index of the previous triangle, the VS would not need to be invoked at all for any of the missing triangle's vertices:

```
1 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 4
```

Primitive restart is pointless for triangle lists; its main use is to create multiple [fans/strips](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) without having to introduce degenerate triangles or new rendering commands.

Comment: Right, primitive restart was what I was thinking of. But you're right just listing the same thing 3 times is likely a better way